# overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir' error showing on Ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu server 20.04 on a virtualbox virtual machine. It has 20 gb disk space (all used for the OS).
After installation I tried to upgrade my system and it shows :
`[2480.105914] overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'`
The packages are still installing but I am just worried that it's probably something not good and I am new to networking and servers. Any solutions would be helpful
Thank You

Comment: The minimum disk space suggested for the OS is 25 gig and now with snaps that may be too small. I would be looking to increase the disk space for the OS to 40 gig before doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

my dear, the overlaysfs are 'the FileSystem' pointers made during the instalatión of a linux system, as u can notice, that rarely affects your loggin.

In case u wish to fix it (as a first part), u must be sure of:

1. your disk/filesystem is correct, no sector errors, filenames or end of files sign.
2. your command 'apt'/'apt-get' works properly.
3. the firmare used in your machine is updated as newest.

This kind of error are used to jump over SDD drives or SD disks, cause the data aplilance isn't ordered.

You can remake the missing directory , but if u can loggin surely your linux dont use it.

On the other hand to solve completly the trouble you should investigate witch package is useing that directory and discart it manualy from ur ppa or include the package adecuated to your own instalatión.

Be happy.